# redimensionar uma imagem e depois salvar no mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, imagem, file-upload, resize

A partir de um formulário eu quero redimensionar uma imagem só depois e depois salvar no mysql, ou pegar uma imagem já salva no mysql e redimensioná-la e depois atualizar o registro. Agradeço imensamente se alguém puder me ajudar.

*** a tabela no mysql  ***

```
CREATE TABLE `imagemedias` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `imagem` mediumblob,
  `ImagemMimeType` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

***aqui é a classe ***

```
namespace rsi.Entities
{
    public class ImageMedia : Auxiliar
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
        public string ImagemMimeType { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

*** aqui é o form ***

```
<form action="/backend/Images/imagem" method="post" name="form" id="form1" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="__file"  id="__file" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

***aqui é o controller ***

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult imagem(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        ImageMedia imagem = new ImageMedia();
        imagem.Imagem = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        imagem.ImagemMimeType = file.ContentType;
        file.InputStream.Read(imagem.Imagem, 0, file.ContentLength);

        return RedirectToAction("Exibir", new { imagem.Id });
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tem um pacote para isso](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer/), mas acho que não é o que você quer. Tem uma outra forma de fazer que é mais simples, usando [`WebImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage(v=vs.111).aspx), mas a qualidade é menor.

Exemplo:

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult imagem(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (file != null)
    {
        ImageMedia imagem = new ImageMedia();
        imagem.Imagem = new byte[file.ContentLength];
        imagem.ImagemMimeType = file.ContentType;
        file.InputStream.Read(imagem.Imagem, 0, file.ContentLength);

        WebImage webimg = new WebImage(file.InputStream);
        webimg.Resize(100, 100); // Mude pro que você precisar
        // Escreva o resto da lógica para salvar aqui

        return RedirectToAction("Exibir", new { imagem.Id });
    }

    return View(); // Aquele null estava bem errado.
}
```

Para obter um *stream*:

```
var stream = new MemoryStream(webimg.GetBytes());
```

Comment: Muuuito obrigado pela resposta! Eu cheguei a usar o WebImage para redimensionar a imagem, só que aí eu não sei como salvar o resultado desse redimensionamento no mySql, pois WebImage não tem as propriedades de HttpPostedFileBase que eu uso para salvar no mysq (por exemplo, o "InputStream.Read").

Comment: Tem sim. Veja minha edição.

Comment: Olá Cigano, muuuito obrigado pela atenção, mas confesso que não consegui salvar o "stream" resultante no banco de dados mysql, Creio que preciso transformar a imagem redimensionada novamente em HttpPostedFileBase, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: @Lucas Crie outra pergunta explicando o que você está fazendo para salvar em banco de dados.